# DSolve output will not plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I am trying to plot the output of the following:

```
DSolve[{74.44 - (4/25)*T[t] == 71.736*T'[t], T[0] == 293}, T[t], t]
```

It output is:

```
{{T[t] -> 465.25 E^(-0.0022304 t) (-0.370231 + 1. E^(0.0022304 t))}}
```

And my plot function is:

```
Plot[T[t], {t, 0, 3600}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

Which gives a blank plot. What is causing this?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to actually access `T[t]` to do the plot. Also it is better to avoid using inexact numbers with exact solver. Also better to write the ode and ic in separate line so you can see them. No need to cramp all the code in one command/line.

You can either do

```
ode = 74.44 - (4/25)*T[t] == 71736/1000*T'[t];
ic  = T[0] == 293;
sol = DSolve[{ode, ic}, T[t], t]

Plot[T[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 3600}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use `DSolveValue` so you do not have to do the above. Little easier.

```
ode = 74.44 - (4/25)*T[t] == 71736/1000*T'[t];
ic  = T[0] == 293;
sol = DSolveValue[{ode, ic}, T[t], t]

Plot[sol, {t, 0, 3600}, PlotRange -> Full]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 1):

That's because the way you have written the code, `T[t]` remains undefined. You have to enforce the solution of `DSolve` on the function itself.

One way of going about it is as follows:

1. Define the output of `DSolve` to be something. This can be done as follows:

`sltn = DSolve[{74.44 - (4/25)*T[t] == 71.736*T'[t], T[0] == 293}, T[t], t];`

2. Evaluate the function `T[t]` by enforcing the previously found solution and plot it:

`Plot[T[t] /. sltn, {t, 0, 3600}, PlotRange -> Full]`